# offset.top does not decrement or increment accordingly when using jquery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `$().offset().top` to get the distance between the selected element to the top of the document and log the value inside of scroll event. The code looks like following

```
$('.element').scroll(function() {
    console.log($('.another-element').offset().top);
});
```

As a result, I am getting like `1939, 1929, 1920, 1912, 1905, 1899` instead of `1939, 1938, 1937, 1936,1935` and etc.It looks like skipping some value.

How I can get the decrement or increment the top value when scroll?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039258/while-scrolling-if-scrolltop-equals-to-or-reaches-a-value-execute-event

Comment: or even: http://iwearshorts.com/blog/measuring-user-scroll-with-jquery/